# Is it recommended to make general partials for modals, drop-downs etc in Laravel Blade?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am looking for a very general way to include bootstrap components in my blade view. For example let's say I need a drop down in my view, should I make a partial called `dropdown.blade.php` with code as follows:

```
<div class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        @foreach ($options as $option)
        <li><a href="{{$option["href"]}}">{{$option["name"]}}</a></li>
        @endforeach
      </ul>
</div>
```

and use it in my view in the following way:

```
  @include('partials.dropdown', 
          array("options"=>array(
          ["href"=>"#", "name"=>"Profile"],
          ["href"=>"#", "name"=>"Report"],
          )))
```

Even we can make it more generic by adding options for button name etc. Is it a good or preferable way to do it or should we use copy-paste method from bootstrap website to our views every time? Is there any package that is doing this sort of work? Can we make it in more elegant way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a good idea if you are going to re-use the component a lot.  I think the more elegant way to do it would be to create custom blade directives:

https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade#extending-blade

Then you could do, for instance:

```
@dropdown($options, 'btn-primary')
```

I would also provide an argument for a custom element ID or name, so you can reference it elsewhere on the page as needed.

This gets a little more complex with things like modals. I think you'd want to register multiple blade directives so you could do something like

```
@startmodal
@modaltitle('Title')
@startmodalbody

    Some body content

@endmodalbody
@endmodal
```